# Why zend studio keeps warning me of functions with no definition for standard PhP functions?

Tags: php

[image]

Basically Zend complaints that function like print_r or is_null, and stuff is not defined.

How can they? It's standard PhP function.'

Because of this, I didn't get warning if I write mt_rand(10), for example, which is a wrong syntax.

debug_backtrace works though.

Comment: Hello? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

I found the file:
`<projectRoot>/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/.buildpath`

and copied it to the `<projectRoot>/` and to the `<projectRoot>/MyMainCodeFolder/`

If you don't have `.buildpath` file to copy, create a new one with the following text inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<buildpath>
    <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
    <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.php.core.LANGUAGE"/>
</buildpath>
```

You'll have to close and re-open the project, then go to the Projects menu and do a clean. A few minutes will be needed for Zend Studio to re-build the projects, and you might want to close and re-open the project after 15 minutes or so.